# Is initializing with "var{args}" a new feature of C++0x, or merely syntactic sugar?

Tags: c++, c++11, syntactic-sugar, initializer-list

I was reading the [C++0x faq](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html) and came across the section detailing initializer lists.  The examples were mostly variations of:

```
vector<int> vi = { 1, 2, 3 };
vector<int> vj({1, 2, 3});
// etc.
```

However, also listed was the form:

```
vector<int> vk{2};
```

This form appears elsewhere in the faq, and I am curious as to whether it is semantically different from the initial two forms, or just syntactic sugar for `vk({x, y, z})`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One is *uniform initialization*, and the other is *initializer lists*. They are two different things, although as you can see, they can produce similar syntax.

```
vector<int> vk{2};
```

is a uniform initialization- the other two are initializer lists.

Comment: There is also the form that is pure uniform initialization: `std::vector<int> vk{1, 2, 3};`

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me. In `vector<int> vk{2}` you use an initializer list too.

Answer (score 6):

The `({1, 2, 3})` form calls the constructors of `vector<int>` directly, and passes as first argument a `{1, 2, 3}`. You could have passed more arguments

```
vector<int> vk({1, 2, 3}, myAllocator);
```

If `vector<int>` would not have a constructor whose first parameter is an `initializer_list` or of another type that could be initialized by `{1, 2, 3}` (like, another container class), it would not work. In your case it works because `vector<int>` in fact has a constructor whose first parameter is a `initializer_list<int>`. This is just like in normal function calls

```
void f(vector<int> const& vk);
int main() { f({1, 2, 3}); }
```

If you omit the parentheses, as in `vector<int> vk{1, 2, 3}`, the exact meaning depends on the class. A `vector<int>` has an initializer list constructor, which is a constructor with a first parameter of type `initializer_list<int>` (optionally a reference to it), and all other params with default arguments. If the class has such a constructor, then the initializer list is passed to that constructor. Alternatively the class could simply be an aggregate (like `struct A { int a; int b; int c; };`, the initializer list would then init the members) or have a constructor that accepts `3` separate `int` arguments.

Finally the `= { 1, 2, 3 }` form is almost identical to the version omitting the parentheses (i.e just removing `=`), except that it forbids to use explicit constructors (i.e had they declared it as `explicit vector(initializer_list<int>);` or had they declared a `explicit vector(int, int, int);` instead, it would result in an error if you use `= { 1, 2, 3 }`).

Answer (score 0):

The uniform initialization prevents narrowing conversions i.e. conversions that would cause loss of data:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<float> v{1.0F, 2.0F, 3.0F}; // OK: 

std::vector<float> w{1.0, 2.0, 3.0}; // OK: doubles could be put into floats without loss.

std::vector<int> j{1.1, 2.2, 3.3}; // error: narrowing

std::vector<int> k{1L, 2L, 3L}; // OK: the long numbers can be represented as int without loss.

std::vector<int> l{0xfacebeefL, 0xdeadbabeL, 0xfadecabeL}; // error: narrowing.
```